# Photo transfer from Android device (no screen) to Android smartphone

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-camera, android-wifi, file-transfer

I am working on an Android pastime project. I have a camera device that runs on Android 8.1. This camera device doesn't have a screen. I am trying to identify the best way to transfer photos from the camera device to my smartphone. So, I see a few options.

1. Pair the camera device with my smartphone over Bluetooth. This way, I can transfer photos over Bluetooth. In this approach, I will be building a background Android service and pushing it to the camera which can take care of transferring the photos. Ref: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/transfer-data
2. Have a hotspot turned on on my smartphone. Connect the camera device with the smartphone's hotspot. This way, I can upload the photos captured to Firebase or some other cloud platform and later pull the photos on the smartphone. The only problem I see is that the hotspot should be always on.
3. Make the camera device utilize the data connection of my smartphone. I am not sure if this is feasible.

I am evaluating these options to identify which will be a better option. I am trying to understand what kind of Android services I would have to build and push to the camera device and my smartphone. Any thoughts/insights are welcome.

Details about the camera device:

1. The camera device (camera module) has both Bluetooth and wifi capabilities.
2. The camera device is not stationary. So it can't be connected with home wifi or specific wifi. But the camera will always remain closer to my smartphone.
3. As the camera runs on Android, I can build services/APKs and push them to the camera. The same applies to my smartphone.

I am trying to find more details on how the photo transfer works on devices like Google glass.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would go with Wi-Fi Direct or Wifi hotspot just for faster transfer and plenty of libs and implementations for IP. Bluetooth is significantly slower and you will probably write a lot more code for handling file transfer

and when talking about IP connection - I would go with [`libstreaming`](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming). In there you have an RTSP server, common solution in IP cams and similar kind devices. It will stream video live, I'm not sure it is capable to do photo during this, but for sure you could add such feature. And you have ready-to-go solutions for handling camera and data transferring through Wi-Fi, based on some RFCs and official docs, not some custom not-so-reliable implementations

PS. Google Glass is a bad sample in this case, it needs Internet connection to work...

PS2. Yep, this answer is opinion-based, this kind questions are in fact forbidden on SO...

Comment: Thanks @snachmsm! The only issue I see with Wifi hotspot is that it should be always on so that the camera device can be connected to the phone.